# Pandas multi-indexing error: MultiIndex slicing requires the index to be lexsorted

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Can anyone please advise why I am getting this multi-index not sorted error?

```
mindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
                                        [[2013,2014],[1,2]],
                                        names = ['Year', 'Visit']
                                    )
mcolumn = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
                                        [['Sue','Bob','John'],['Heart Rate', 'Temperature']],
                                        names = ['Name','Parameter']
                                    )

data = np.random.randint(44, 92, size=(4,6))
df = pd.DataFrame( data, columns = mcolumn, index = mindex)
idx = pd.IndexSlice

df.loc[ idx[2013, 2], idx['Bob':'Guido', 'Heart Rate']  ]
```

> Error: 'MultiIndex slicing requires the index to be lexsorted: slicing on
>   levels [0], lexsort depth 0'

Somehow when I had executed the same code from the same Jupyter Notebook around 1 month ago, I had not faced this error. But now I am facing it. Any tips?

Comment: Did you upgrade pandas versions?  What version of pandas are you running now?   I think you can fix this error by sorting axis `df.sort_index(axis=1).loc[ idx[2013, 2], idx['Bob':'Guido', 'Heart Rate']  ]`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion for sorting, but I am still getting the same error. My Pandas version is 1.0.1

Comment: Upgrade to pandas 1.0.3.. sort_index(axis=1) works for me with pandas 1.0.3.

Comment: I did upgrade to 1.0.3, still the same error. This is really frustrating.

Comment: This exact code generates your error with the .sort_index(axis=1)?

Comment: Yes, the exact same code gives me the error.

Comment: Are you running it in Jupyter notebook?  Stop and start your kernel.  What does pd.__version__ return?

Comment: Yes, running in Jupyter Notebook. pd.__version__  gives 1.0.3. Also, I have restarted the Kernel multiple times already, still same error encountered.